# Uninstalling Ubuntu from Dual boot Windows 10 - Set default boot to Windows bootloader prior to uninstall

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I just installed Ubuntu and haven't started using it yet. My hard drive is divided into messy partitions here and there, so now I want to uninstall and re-install again.

I don't have a Windows 10 bootable DVD/USB and my PC uses UEFI.

So, is it enough to just set boot options, default boot to Windows bootloader before deleting the partitions with Ubuntu, using Windows Disk Management tool?

Or will I need Windows installation disk still?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If Windows 10 pre-installed then UEFI, and reset to Windows as default should be all you need. You need at least a repair/recovery disk for every system you install. Ubuntu installer works for your Ubuntu install. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026852/windows-create-a-recovery-drive If UEFI, you will have lots of partitions, many are vital. For reinstall only use Something Else. https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: From Windows10 up there usually is an "instalation DVD" dump on one of the harddrive partition so the DVD isn't needed anymore. I actually didn't have to do anything when I removed an additinal installed Ubuntu from my dualboot.

Comment: @oldfred Windows 10 pre-installed HP probook.

Comment: @derHugo Windows 10 pre-installed machine. Could you tell me what exactly you did to remove Ubuntu from dualboot?

Comment: Saved my data, booted Windows10 and formatted the Ubuntu partition. And expanded the windows partition again to all free disk space. I wanted to repair the grub thing but when I rebooted to my surprise I realized Windows already just booted as desired.